# Convert all fields ending with "id" to integer using convert in mutate?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Currently I am doing something like this in my logstash config file :

```
filter {
    ...
    mutate {
        ...
        convert => {
            "blahId" => "integer"
            "blahblahId" => "integer"
            ...
            ...
            "b...blahId" => "integer"
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So basically I want to convert all the fields ending with "Id" to type integer. Is there a way to do that in one line? Something like `"*Id" => "integer"` which does that ?

**Edit** : I tried

```
convert => {
    "*Id" => "integer"
}
```

As I expected, didn't work.

Using ruby filter perhaps ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also facing this problem right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not specifically an answer to this but this is what I end up doing :

```
ruby {
        code => "
            fieldArray = event['kvmess'].split('|');
            for field in fieldArray
                name = field.split('=')[0];
                value = field.split('=')[1];
                if value =~ /\A\d+\Z/
                    event[name] = value.to_i
                else
                    event[name] = value
                end
            end
        "
    }
```

My `kvmess` was like *"blahId=123|blahblahId=456|some=thing|b..blahId=789"*.
So this converted all keys having numeric values to type integer.

There is a plugin - [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) meant specifically for this but it does not have the functionality to change datatype to int so I ended up using this ruby plugin instead.

Comment: hanks you for posting this answer. Was searching for the same approach. Was yousing kv, but stucked with the need to convert each dynamic value to int type. 

Will test your variant now.